# What is this "checked id" attribute inside the <input> tag? Normally it is "id" attribute

Tags: html

I am looking at the sourcecode of a website, and come across the following code snippets

```
<input type="checkbox" name="age" value="1" checked id="age"><label for="age">I am an adult and capable citizen</label>
```

what is the attribute "checked id" as oppose to the "id" attribute that we normally see inside the  tag, thanks.

Comment: `checked` is an attribute you place to make a checkbox 'ticked' by default. `id` is a different attribute, which means the id of the element is named 'age'. no such thing as "checked id". take the word `checked` and place it just before the closing `>` of your input. same effect, but readable.

Comment: Hi Stavm, thanks for your help, cheers. :)

Comment: @Stavm: You should post that as an answer, it's a much better answer than the two that have been posted in the meantime.

Comment: @Stavm, i agree with what BoltClock said.

Answer (score 1):

`checked` is an attribute you place to make a checkbox 'ticked' by default.

`id` is a different attribute. the id of the element you posted is 'age'.

There is no such thing as `checked id`. 
might as well take the word `checked` and place it just before the closing `>` of your input. same effect, but readable.

Answer (score 0):

All fine, look at it closely. input type="checkbox", so it may have "checked"

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like chekced id. id is unique identifier and checked is default value for type checkbox. You can do something like

```
<input type="checkbox" id="age" name="age" value="1" checked ><label for="age">I am an adult and capable citizen</label>
```